# Is that possible to delete the phone contact from my application

Tags: android

I fetched all contacts from phone and listed in list view.i am able to remove the local contact in my listview as well as database now i want to remove the phone contact is that possible. For removing purpose i am using the following code.

```
if (position == 1) {
    db.deleteContact(item_position + 1);
    from.remove(item_position);
    note.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the selected item name and assign it to the name then try the following code.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                        String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
                        String[] params = new String[] {name};

                        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withSelection(where, params)
                                .build());
                        try {
                            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted the contact with name '" + name +"'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        from.remove(item_position);
                        note.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to delete contact from Contact Uri

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

1.Get all contact from device and store into one container

while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```

2.Select the contact from container`
then pass selected value for performe delete operation

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()); }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am not able to get your code it is puzzle.Can you explain in simple

Comment: ok .. first you get all contact and store into container..now.you want to delete specific contact so select contact from container and pass this info last code i have written deleteContact() mehtod .. are you getting??

Comment: My contacts are in list view when i am selecting the list view item the contacts should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It may be same as deleting a particular log from the mobile, not sure of how far it can be done.
The code for deleting a particular call log is as follows:

```
public void DeleteNumFromCallLog(ContentResolver resolver, String strNum) {
    try {
        String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";
        Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse(strUriCalls);
        if (null != resolver) {
            resolver.delete(UriCalls, CallLog.Calls._ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { strNum });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all we need. To delete Contact with phone number and name given

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name) 
{
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

    try 
    {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) 
                {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

And remind to add read/write contact permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Godra i want use my list view item to delete the contact details how to do that.

Comment: From list and phone(device) as well?